# Unix tar compressed folder not opening on windows

Tags: windows-7, linux, compression, tar

I used command `tar -cvzf upload.tar upload` to compress my upload folder, but when i'll extract it on widows using 7-Zip it shows up as just a single file, not folder.

And the uplad folder isn't symlink - it is real directory. File size is correct, but it is not a folder on windows

**Okay - found the problem. Caused by the -z flag. So running `tar -cvf upload.tar upload` works. Why is that so? Docs say that z flag - 'Compress or decompress files automatically.'**

Why is that so?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably misled the Windows utility by using extension `tar` on a gzipped file. As you're using gzip compression by using the `-z` flag, the common file-types are `.tgz` and `.tar.gz`. I have no idea whether or not 7-zip supports this. Alternatively you can drop the `z` flag.

Comment: 7-zip supports compressed tarballs just fine.

Answer (score 1):

That is due to historical reasons.

Back in the days of yore when compression was still very expensive there was this program to backup data to tapes. It was called **T**ape **AR**chive. A tape device on unix is just a file, so it was also possible to dump this archive to a file. That file normally gets the extension `.tar`.

It you wanted to compress this a file (E.g. a freshly made backup) you used the program `compress` which added the extension `.Z`   The resulting file then got both extentions. (`file.tar.Z`)

Later versions allowed you to combine these with the `-z` flag in tar. They also after substituted gzip for compress.  The resulting gzip compressed tar file usually have the extension `.tar.gz`, or on some windows computers (due to 8.3 limitations) `.tgz`.

Answer (score 0):

Scroll to the right in 7-zip and you'll probably see it shows a full folder path.

If you drag it to your desktop, does it write the folder (and any subfolders/files)?